# Replacement for Infura site

Tags: json-rpc, infura

I have been using Infura site for accessing main Ethereum network, but newly this site has changed its services and don't service `send` methods.

I searched a little and found [Quicknode](https://quiknode.io/) site, but unfortunately it is nor free of charge. I also found [Alchemy](https://alchemyapi.io/) site, but it cannot send email for registration, how can I trust it to operate properly.

So I ask you to introduce a replacement for Infura site that response to JSON RPC calls.

Comment: "but newly this site has changed its services and don't service `send` methods" Could you explain what you mean specifically?

Comment: `.send` method in web3.js does not work in Infoura RPC. @smarx

Comment: Infura doesn't support any operations that require it to know your private key (thankfully!), but as far as I know, Infura has _always_ worked that way. You said something has recently changed, but you haven't said what.

Comment: `send` method doesn't need to send your private key to RPC server. you should use your private key in web3.js and it encodes your transaction and send it to infura. 
P.N: Our program was working on nfura, but newly Infura announced that it doesn't support `send` method from now on.

Comment: If Infura announced that, please link to the announcement. If you need more help, you'll need to define what you mean by "`send` method". Which RPC method are you invoking? If you're not sure, maybe you can share your code.

Comment: https://blog.infura.io/infura-dashboard-transition-update-c670945a922a @smarx

Comment: Nothing in that post indicates any sort of change to the supported RPC methods. Perhaps your code stopped working because you didn't update your connection URL as specified in that post. If you're still struggling, consider sharing your code and the specific error message you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use our free test nodes - https://eth7.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can take a Ethereum Node Developer Survey and get access to a demo QuikNode here: https://forms.gle/qmP6pF1zmHPjJ4dV7 (as of writing, the demo node expires April 27 2019).

Answer (score 0):

Last time I used Infura it required more gas than was estimated by Web3, and the error message was really unhelpful. If you increase the gas price to 1.5x what Web3 suggests, it will probably work.

I also recommend using any service other than Infura, since it is a central point of failure for the Ethereum network. If your application is using more than trivial value, you should be running your own Ethereum full node for it.

Answer (score 0):

QuikNode has a new service called `QuikNode API`, with a 100% free tier so you can get access to Ethereum MainNet just by registering for an account. [QuikNode.io](https://quiknode.io)

Answer (score 0):

[Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/) has been extremely reliable for me and I've found their debugging tools to be super useful.